# How to use arduino nano to switch an 230V AC motor on/off?

Tags: arduino, motor, switches, ac, relay

I want to switch on and off an 230V AC motor with a relay what is controlled by an arduino nano. 
The on time and off time would be able to set by a 3-position slider switch. So would be 3 different on-off time available. I want a status led for the relay to show if the relay is activated.The Arduino nano will be powered by a 5v mobile charger.

schematics:

[image]

the motor:

[image]

[the relay module](http://www.ebay.com/itm/5V-10A-one-1-Channel-Relay-Module-With-optocoupler-For-PIC-AVR-DSP-ARM-Arduino-/310636242802?)

[image]

program code:

```
const int switchPin1 = 2;    // D2
const int switchPin2 = 3;    // D3
const int switchPin3 = 4;    // D4
const int RelayPin = 5 ; // D5
const int ledPin = 6;      // D13 status led

int switchState1 = LOW;            
int switchState2 = LOW;              
int switchState3 = LOW;            
int mode = 0;
int timeON[3] = {30000,60000, 60000}; // 0.5 min, 1min, 1 min
int timeOFF[3] ={30000,60000, 120000}; // 0.5 min, 1min, 2min
int relayON = timeON[0];
int relayOFF = timeOFF[0];


void setup() {  
  pinMode(switchPin1, INPUT);  
  pinMode(switchPin2, INPUT);  
  pinMode(switchPin3, INPUT);  
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RelayPin, OUTPUT);  
  digitalWrite(switchPin1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(switchPin2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(switchPin3, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  digitalWrite(RelayPin, LOW);
}


void loop() {
    switchState1 = digitalRead(switchPin1);
    switchState2 = digitalRead(switchPin2);
    switchState3 = digitalRead(switchPin3);
    if (!switchState1 && switchState2 && switchState3) { mode = 0;}// mode selection
    if (!switchState2 && switchState1 && switchState3) { mode = 1;}
    if (!switchState3 && switchState1 && switchState2) { mode = 2;}
    relayON = timeON[mode];
    relayOFF = timeOFF[mode];

    digitalWrite(RelayPin, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    delay(relayON);
    digitalWrite(RelayPin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    delay(relayOFF);
  }
```

Will this work or is there something that I didn't take into account? Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Oops, the diode to protect is in the module...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The relay claims to be capable of 10A at 230VAC, and the motor claims to run on 0.75A at 230V.  Should be OK.
2. Your program logic looks good, and the pins match your schematic.
3. The timer cycle will only change after the current cycle is finished.  Just to be sure that was your intent.  You can twiddle the switch all you want, but the only setting that counts is the one that is active when the current cycle ends.